# C# Jagged array: outside the bounds of the array issue

Tags: c#, jagged-arrays

I have a jagged array declared as:

```
char[][] m = new char[10][];
```

Later it is populated.

```
System.Text.StringBuilder s = new System.Text.StringBuilder(c);
for (int x = 0; x < 10; x++)
    s.Append('=');

    for (int x = 0; x < 10; x++) m[x] = s.ToString().ToCharArray();
```

If I perform the below operations, I get an error on the second dimension:

```
Console.WriteLine(String.Format("width={0}", m.GetLength(0)));
Console.WriteLine(String.Format("height={0}", m.GetLength(1))); <---- ERROR HERE
```

Any ideas?

Comment: It's a jagged array, not a square array (which you declare with `char[,] maz`). Each sub array is going to have a different length. that you check with `maz[index].Length`.

Comment: Don't use [`GetLenght()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.getlength(v=vs.110).aspx), rather [`Length`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.length(v=vs.110).aspx) of individual item of first array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are confusing square arrays and jagged arrays. A jagged array is also known as an array of arrays, and it looks like this:

```
char[][] a = new char[10][];
```

Each element in a jagged array is an array in its own right, and it can have a completely different length from any of the others:

```
a[0] = new char[1];
a[1] = new char[100];
a[2] = new char[5];
...
a[9] = new char[999999];
```

As you can see, `GetLength(1)` makes no sense on a jagged array. What would it even return? To get the lengths of the second level of arrays, you would have to iterate through them and call their various `Length` properties:

```
for (int i = 0; i < a.Length; i++)
{
    int length = a[i].Length;
}
```

For your purposes, you probably want to use a square array (also known as a 2D array) instead:

```
char[,] a = new char[10,10];
```

Unlike a jagged array, the second dimension of a square array is guaranteed to be the same length. That means `GetLength(1)` can return a value with confidence.

Answer (score 1):

[`Array.GetLength(int dimension)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.getlength(v=vs.110).aspx) is only for **multi-dimensional** arrays. Your array 'm' is *not* multi-dimensional, but *jagged*.

That means it's an array with element type `char[]`.

So you only have one dimension (with length `10`) and `GetLength(1)` throws the error.

You can get `m[i].Length` for i from `0` to `9`. But only if you initialized the elements:

```
m[0] = new char[10];
int l = m[0].Length; // 10
```

Comment: Technically speaking, you *can* use `GetLength` for any kind of array. It will just throw an exception if you try to query a dimension that doesn't exist, and for every non-multidimensional array, the only dimension that exists is `0`. (There's also the fact that there's literally no reason to use `GetLength` on a non-multidimensional array since `Length` is both faster and more convenient.)